# Connect Macbook Air to Macbook Pro in target disk mode

Tags: macbook-pro

Is there anyway to connect a Macbook Air (11-Inch, Late 2010) to a Macbook Pro in target disk mode?

The Macbook Air does not support Thunderbolt and also does not have a FireWire port.  It just has two USB ports and a mini display port.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Just out of curiosity, what model is the MBA ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to use the target disk mode without Thunderbolt or FireWire cable. It wont work on USB or mini display ports.

Answer (score 1):

If the USB port on the Air supports USB 3, you can use two adapters to use Target Disk mode over Gigabit Ethernet (USB->Ethernet and Thunderbolt->Ethernet) - but otherwise, you're out of luck.